# Iterator on a map never atteins map.end()

Tags: c++, iterator, maps

why the iteration in the code below doesn't work ? I mean the iterator is incremented but evaluating this expression `o!=RateCurve.end()` always give `true`.

i need such a function because i'm using it in a wrapper of a map to contruct an interest rate curve.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <math.h>       
#include <string>       
#include <map>          
#include <exception>    
#include <vector>       
#include <stdio.h>      

using namespace std;


map<double, double>::iterator getIt(map<double, double> o){
    return o.begin();
}

int main ()
{
    map<double, double> RateCurve;

    RateCurve[3.3  ]=0.034 ;
    RateCurve[1.2  ]=0.03  ;
    RateCurve[0.2  ]=.001  ;
    RateCurve[6.1  ]=.023  ;



    map<double, double>::iterator o=getIt(RateCurve);
    while (o!=RateCurve.end()){

        cout << "RateCurve[" << o->first << "] = " << o->second << endl;
        ++o;
    }

}
```

Comment: it's unrelated to your question, but I can't see why you need to define `getIt` when you can directly call `begin()` - your function does nothing more than the latter.

Comment: `for ( auto const& o : RateCurve ) { ... }` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

```
getIt(map<double, double> o)
```

You copy the `map`, so the iterator returned points into an entirely unrelated `map` to the one you wanted. Worse, the copy gets destroyed at the end of the function call, and the iterator you try to use is no longer valid, so you have [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make `getIt` take a reference, and since you don't actually change the elements, you can make it `const` too. Then you need to change the return type:

```
std::map<double, double>::const_iterator
getIt(map<double, double> const& o)
{
    return o.begin();
}
```

---

Also, please reconsider your use of bad practices [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).

Comment: When the data is only used for reading I would even suggest to pass a const reference and return `map<double, double>::const_iterator`.

Comment: so instead of using namespace, should I use std:: each time?

Comment: @Daveddd That is my preference, and one shared by most experienced C++ programmers I know. It makes the code a lot easier to read, even if it makes it slightly slower to type (and I have a vim mapping to enter `std::` with one keystroke).

Comment: @Daveddd You can explicitly use names out of a namespace. E.g. `using std::cout; using std::endl;` will still let you write `cout << "Hello" << endl;`, but you won't accidentially have ambigious names.